How do I add a classpath to the JAR file using Intellij?
So I have the application working fine except for one issue. In summary, I have a jar file that runs the app and when the app launches, I can search for any of the test files like Test1, Test2, and so on as shown in the screenshot. I have a problem where I can search for test files only in the src folder, but as you can see I have test files in the same directory but when searching for those, they can't be found. I want to set a classpath in the jar file so that test classes can be located in the same directory as the jar file and run from there.
enter image description here
So far, I tried going to Project Structures and selecting the .jar file, didn't work. Even tried Eclipse IDE to open the JAR file and "Add external JARs" but that option was not selectible for some reason as shown in the screenshot below. I would like to solve the problem with Intellij as it's the IDE I use the most but any solution is welcome.
enter image description here
